# 2018 version - open link in FB native app & NOT in browser

Tags: facebook

How do I get this button to take the user to the FB app in the user's mobile?

This is the code for now - My link is taking him to the browser:

```
<a style="color:#3b5998;text-decoration:none;cursor:pointer;width:100%;" href="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/group/join/popup/?group_id=170986033537864&amp;source=email_campaign_plugin" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdRlQ.png)

Comment: What is your code?

Comment: Sorry, just added it to the question

href="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/group/join/popup/?group_id=170986033537864&amp;source=email_campaign_plugin" target="_blank" rel="noopener">

Comment: Where did you get that link from?